# Testing asynchronus delay function in Karma

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, promise, karma-jasmine

I have a bit of an unusual problem that I haven't found any solution for and I've been trying for quite some time. I have created a function called delay that basically creates a new Promise which resolves itself after a given amount of time. The purpose of this function is to be able to cause a delay in a chain of promises. It looks a bit like this:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
});

let test = '';

const func = () => {
    delay(1000).then(() => {
        test = 'kek';
    });
};

describe('unit tests', () => {
    it('test function func', () => {
        // Act
        func();
        // Assert
        expect(test).toEqual('kek');
    });
});
```

The problem is testing, the unit test I have provided in this example will fail because it's only after the 1000 ms delay that the variable test is set to kek.

I have tried the usual solutions like having a setTimeout inside the unit test, and also tried with jasmine.clock().tick(1001) before asserting but I can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me,

```
import {fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('When ngOnInit is invoked', () => {
    it('should wait and redirect to next page', fakeAsync( () => {
        component.ngOnInit(); // contains delay inside
        tick(2000); // time to wait
        expect(routerService.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('nextStep');
    }));
});
```

Comment: could you explain why this works? (it works for me, which is cool and useful, but some extra background info would greatly benefit the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I actually proposed to do this (at lolex, the timers library) and am now convinced that it's a good thing that this is impossible to override the scheduler for that reason. That's because it can change the ordering of calls which can be very problematic.

Promises always resolve asynchronously, you'll have to make your test async and *return* the promise.

Here is how you'd write that test with an async function:

```
describe('unit tests', () => {
    it('test function func', async () => {
        // Act
        let promise = func(); // wait for it to be ready
        clock.tick(1001); 
        await promise; // wait for the promise to complete.
        // Assert
        expect(test).toEqual('kek');
    });
});
```

This way you won't wait 1000 ms but the test will still work.

Comment: clock.tick() where is this come from? is it from angular core testing ?

Comment: sorry im not sure with lolex? do we need to import `something` so we can use `clock.tick()` ?